# Convert image into 8-Bit color space?

Tags: colors, conversion

Is there a way to use `convert` to transform an image into an 8-bit bitmap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the syntax:

`convert [input-option] input-file [output-option] output-file`

You might be able to accomplish the task as simply as:

`convert file-to-convert -depth 8 output-file`

Tho it may also be:

`convert file-to-convert -depth 8bit output-file`

You can find *all* the possible options on the [convert](https://manpage.me/?q=convert) man page. :)

HTH